# How to delete '$'\n' characters appended to ldd list

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to copy binary dependencies to other folder, so I use `ldd` to see what should be copied.

However the script fails when copying. It "appears" `'$'\n'` characters when binary dependencies are copied.

Something is wrong, but I dont know what. Tried running command per command and cant see the fault.

What is the trouble here ?

Thanks

#### Script code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

chr=/home/myjail
cmds=( bash echo ls rm )

mkdir -p "$chr"/{bin,lib,lib64}

# copy commands
for app in "${cmds[@]}"; do
        echo 'Added command:'"$app"
        cp -v /bin/"$app" "$chr/bin"
done

# copy deps    
for app in "${cmds[@]}";do

        echo 'deps for:'"$app"
        deps="$(ldd /bin/"$app" | egrep -o '/lib.*\.[0-9]')"

        for curdep in "${deps[@]}";do
                echo "$curdep"
                cp -v --parents "$curdep" "$chr"
        done
done
```

#### Script output

```
furby@debian-haptic20:~# ./depcopy.sh
Added command:bash
'/bin/bash' -> '/var/lib/haproxy/bin/bash'
Added command:echo
'/bin/echo' -> '/var/lib/haproxy/bin/echo'
Added command:ls
'/bin/ls' -> '/var/lib/haproxy/bin/ls'
Added command:mysql
'/bin/mysql' -> '/var/lib/haproxy/bin/mysql'
deps for:bash
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
cp: failed to get attributes of '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6'$'\n': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this script for this purpose:

*copydep.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ${#} != 2 ]
then
    echo "usage $0 PATH_TO_BINARY target_folder"
    exit 1
fi

path_to_binary="$1"
target_folder="$2"

# if we cannot find the the binary we have to abort
if [ ! -f "${path_to_binary}" ]
then
    echo "The file '${path_to_binary}' was not found. Aborting!"
    exit 1
fi

# copy the binary itself
echo "---> copy binary itself"
cp --parents -v "${path_to_binary}" "${target_folder}"

# copy the library dependencies
echo "---> copy libraries"
ldd "${path_to_binary}" | awk -F'[> ]' '{print $(NF-1)}' | while read -r lib
do
    [ -f "$lib" ] && cp -v --parents "$lib" "${target_folder}"
done
```

Run it like this:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ bash copydep.sh /bin/ls /tmp/test
---> copy binary itself
/bin -> /tmp/test/bin
'/bin/ls' -> '/tmp/test/bin/ls'
---> copy libraries
/lib -> /tmp/test/lib
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -> /tmp/test/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1' -> '/tmp/test/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1'
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6' -> '/tmp/test/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3' -> '/tmp/test/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3'
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2' -> '/tmp/test/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2'
/lib64 -> /tmp/test/lib64
'/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2' -> '/tmp/test/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0' -> '/tmp/test/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0'

# Result:
$ tree /tmp/test/
/tmp/test/
├── bin
│   └── ls
├── lib
│   └── x86_64-linux-gnu
│       ├── libc.so.6
│       ├── libdl.so.2
│       ├── libpcre.so.3
│       ├── libpthread.so.0
│       └── libselinux.so.1
└── lib64
    └── ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

4 directories, 7 files
```

Comment: Glad to heart that! I'm also using it since years :) (have reviewed and shortened a bit)

Answer (score 0):

Your `deps` variable should be an array, created with [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) and some redirection of [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```sh
mapfile -t deps < <(ldd /bin/"$app" | grep -o '/lib.*\.[0-9]')
```

As you have it, it's treated as a single string, which as you've seen, doesn't work.

Comment: mm, taken from here https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/external-check-and-chroot/2150/14. Why that script works ?¿ This line *for i in $list; do cp -v --parents "$i" "${chr}"; done

Comment: @ppk Quotes (or their lack) make all the difference in shells.

Comment: Shell issue ? curious

Comment: @ppk http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashProgramming is a good starting point for learning how bash works. And reading the manual, especially the section on expansion.